# Method execution with the help of callback in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know 2 will be console.logged first and then 1. Is there any way, maybe with callbacks, I can show 1 first and then 2?

```
function first(){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
  }, 500 );
}
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}
first();
second();
```

Comment: Call `second()` in timeout

Comment: Don't call `first` or `second`; just do `console.log(1); console.log(2);`.

Comment: don't use timeout call in `first ` function

Comment: Promise is better than callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `second()`'s call in the `setTimeout`:

```
function first(){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
    second();
  }, 500 );
}
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}
first();
```

You could also bypass `first`, `second` and `setTimeout` completely:

```
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function second(){
  console.log(2);
}

function first(cb){
  // Simulate a code delay
  return setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
     cb();
  }, 500 );
   
}

first(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Solve it by promise a clan and elegant way:

```js
function second() {
 console.log("test2", 2);
}

function first() {
 var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   console.log("test1", 1);
   resolve();
  }, 500);
 });
 return promise;
}

first().then(function () {
 second();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use timeout call in `first` function. or you can use `promises`

for better understanding of `event loop` `callback` execution order read this article
[link](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/). this article explains execution order , which get priority among promise , timeout etc

Hope it will help